Read push notification with API
I need to read PUSH notifications coming from my Reolink camera system to be able to launch some actions.
I have registered to Pushbullet. I have now access to the free version for the test.
I have installed the MS version Pushbullet app on a PC and I have a server on which I need also to receive the push.
The current status is: When Reolink sent a Push, I get in on my mobile phone. I get in on my PC BUT I cannot see it on the server.
I tried 2 methods to see it:

with curl and the command:

curl -H "Access-Token:tokenhidden" --get https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes


with a python script.  here is the function to read Push.

def check_notifications(pb):
    pushes = pb.get_pushes()
    for push in pushes:
        # Imprimer toutes les données de la notification
        print(f"Notification Data: {push}")
        # Vérifier si la notification a été rejetée
        if not push.get('dismissed'):
            # Traiter la notification en fonction de son contenu
            if 'body' in push:
                notification_text = push['body']
                print(f"Notification body: {notification_text}")
                if "trigger command" in notification_text:
                    execute_command(r"d:\scripts\Push_detected.bat")
            # Rejeter la notification pour éviter de la traiter à nouveau
            dismiss_notification(pb, push['iden'])

In both cases, I cannot see the Reolink Push (or other push like Whatapps...). I can only see the notification sent with the Pushbullet app (in 'People').
What do I do wrongly? Thanks
